# share 'form fragment' between createForm.html, updateForm.html on thymeleaf

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I use thymeleaf on spring.

I don't want to produce duplicated html page createForm.html and updateForm.html.
Maybe It requires copy & paste.

My code is below.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" th:action="${!template.new@{/templates}" method="post"
th:object="${template}">
...
</form>
```

When template is before saving(=create), action is '/templates'.

When tempalte is after saving(=update), action is '/templates/UUID/edit'.

=> It is rails convention.

Comment: I resolved this problem using  th:action="@{${#httpServletRequest.servletPath}}"

Answer (score 0):

You can also add this address to the `ModelMap`:

`modelMap.add("address", "/templates")`
`th:action="@{${address}}"`

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="objectName">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" th:value="${object.name}" name="name"
                       id="objectName" placeholder="Name"/>
            </div>
```

> bottom HTML

```
 <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name 1</th>
                    <th>Name 2</th>
                    <th>Name 3</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr data-th-each="eachObject : ${obj}">
                    <td><a data-th-text="${eachObject.name}" th:href="@PATH/edit?Name=}+${eachObject.name}">...</a></td>
                    <td data-th-text="${eachObject.name2}">...</td>
                    <td data-th-text="${eachObject.name3}">...</td>
                    <td><a th:href="@{/PATH/delete?objname=}+${eachObject.name}">delete</a></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

> **Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String createMethod(Model model) {
        Object obj = new Object();
        model.addAttribute("Object", obj);    
        return "htmlpage";
    }
```

> **controller**

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/form/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String campaignPost(@ModelAttribute("object") Object obj, Principle prin, Model model){
 service.save(obj);
}
```